# Webscraping an angularjs site

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am attempting to webscrape an angularjs site using beautifulsoup. The site is an angularjs site and completely generated from javascript.

The site is: https://sports.bovada.lv/baseball/mlb/pitcher-props-market-group

I thought I could just use the phantomjs webdriver strategy.
Here is what I have:

```
PHANTOMJS_PATH = './phantomjs.exe'
bovadaURL = 'https://sports.bovada.lv/baseball/mlb/pitcher-props-market-group'
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(PHANTOMJS_PATH)
driver.get(bovadaURL)
driver.set_window_position(0, 0)
driver.set_window_size(100000, 200000)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
time.sleep(15) # wait to load
# now print the response
print(driver.page_source)
```

However, not getting the output desired.. this outputs:

```
<html><head></head><body></body></html>
```

Any ideas on where to go from here? Running out of ideas..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried requests? i just tried a quick and dirty script and it got more than `<html><head><body>` tags.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import requests, bs4

res = requests.get('https://sports.bovada.lv/baseball/mlb/pitcher-props-market-group')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,'html.parser')

print(res.text)
```

inserted the print statement to test the response and this is the output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"... more
<!--[if IE]><![endif]-->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="x-dns-prefetch-control" content="on">... more
<meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
<link href="https://sports.bovada.lv/base... more
etc... much longer html stuff
```

and as for bs4, seems to work smoothly as well, if i just do something fast like looking for all the links (they use `<link>` tags) then this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import requests, bs4

res = requests.get('https://sports.bovada.lv/baseball/mlb/pitcher-props-market-group')

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,'html.parser')
links = soup.find_all('link')

for link in links:
    print(link.attrs['href'])
```

produces the following output:

```
>python test.py
//cdn13-a.imagestore.lv
//cdn13-b.imagestore.lv
//cdn13-c.imagestore.lv
https://cdn13-a.imagestore.lv/sites/site10/themes/websites_bovada_theme/favicon.ico
https://cdn13-a.imagestore.lv/static/site10/favicons/apple-icon-57x57.png
https://cdn13-b.imagestore.lv/static/site10/favicons/apple-icon-60x60.png
https://cdn13-b.imagestore.lv/static/site10/favicons/apple-icon-72x72.png
https://cdn13-c.imagestore.lv/static/site10/favicons/apple-icon-76x76.png
https://cdn13-b.imagestore.lv/static/site10/favicons/apple-icon-114x114.png
etc...
```

does that help?

EDIT:
so as before you cant use a headless browser. so you need to use something regular like firefox. But first (if you havent done so already) you need to get the geckodriver, find it here:

https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

you need to add this to your PATH.
once thats done you should be able to run selenium on that site and go through bs4 again as usual.

[image]

Comment: think my issue may be that my connection is not loading as fast as I need it to be

Comment: think that is my usse, sometimes i am able to load the page.. and sometimes i can't..

Comment: it must be a speed thing

Comment: are you running via console or script? my internet is pretty fast, and i used a script, so i cant imagine my connection is at all slow enough to make a difference.

Comment: script..not sure what to think

Comment: you might have to work with selenium then, but you cant use a headless webdriver. javascript wont load in a headless browser because it wont take any client side code. so you should use something regular like a chrome or firefox driver. it'll be slower, but at least you are sure to get the results you desire.

Comment: for the selenium example, see EDIT: